# How to update existing wotkitem(feature) card state through API azure devops without using PATCH http method

Tags: azure-devops, rpa

I have a Feature card with state New i want to change the state of this card using API. I work on AA tool of RPA which doesn't support PATCH method. i want to update only "System.State" is there API query to update state?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: But for now, the available rest api uses the PATCH method, which does not meet your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround ,you can try to change the state via [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-boards-work-item-update):

```
az boards work-item update --id [--state]
```

Comment: can you please tell me how authentication works here? for API i was using Personal Access Token to authenticate. i have not yet installed azure CLI i am going through document and haven't worked on powershell as well. If i give username and password in the powershell scripts does this work? and is it safe?

Comment: Run `az login` to sign in. Note that we support only interactive or log in using user name and password with az login. We do not support use of service principals with az login. You would need to use a [PAT token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) in this case. To get started, see [Get started with Azure DevOps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops).

Comment: i tried with az boards work-item show --288 it gave error as ' az boards work-item show: error: the following arguments are required: --id '. the organization url for which i am working is "https://$Variable$.visualstudio.com/Abc". does Azure CLI works for this?

Comment: it worked for me with azure cloud shell but i want to test in powershell. thank you:)